# AWS Javascript/Typescript SDK download s3 file

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk-js, aws-sdk-nodejs

I would like to use the AWS Javascript SDK to download a file from s3.

My current code is

```
import {
    S3Client,
    GetObjectCommand,
} from "@aws-sdk/client-s3";

const s3 = new S3Client({region: REGION});


const downloadParams = {Bucket: bucketName, Key: keyName};

const downloadFile = async () => {
    try {
        const data = await s3.send(new GetObjectCommand(downloadParams));
        // fs.writeFileSync("output.txt", data.Body);
        // fs.writeFile("output.txt", data.Body);
        console.log("Success, bucket returned", data);
    } catch (err) {
        console.log("Error", err);
    }
}
downloadFile();
```

But I am not sure how to get the file data from the return data.

Data.body does not get the file data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer to this JS example in the AWS Github repo. It shows you how to get the object from the Amazon S3 bucket. It is returned as a ReadableStream.

https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/blob/master/javascriptv3/example_code/s3/src/s3_getobject.js

Updated URL:

https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/blob/main/javascriptv3/example_code/s3/actions/get-object.js

Comment: This link results in a 404

Comment: link was updated - check now

Comment: still getting 404

Comment: 404 not found :/

Comment: I updated it in the response.